# Can we do streaming and logical replication in postgresql Slave at same time?

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication

We have PostgresSQL cluster with 1 master and 2 slave configuration , we want to enable logical replication from Slave , as the master a pretty work heavy database , we don’t want to put more load on DB , Is it possible if we can start both type of replication from any slave currently replicating through streaming replication

we have setup with master it worked , not sure with slave , we did few test run in older vesrion which failed

Answer (score 0):

No, the logical replication primary cannot be a streaming replication standby server.